# Select "Option" Div Hide/Show using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, visible

I am trying to create an auto hide/show function for when someone selects a certain "option" on a select element. Here's what I have for the "selector":

```
<li id="foli16" class="name notranslate">
                    <label class="desc" id="title16" for="Field16">
                        Repeat Pattern
                        <span id="req_16" class="req"></span>
                    </label>
                    <span class="left">
                        <select id="Field16" style="margin-left: 0px;" name="" class="field select">
                            <option value="" <?php echo $doc_selected; ?>>None</option>
                            <option value="" <?php echo $doc_selected; ?>>Daily</option>
                            <option value="" <?php echo $doc_selected; ?>>Weekly</option>
                            <option value="" <?php echo $doc_selected; ?>>Monthly</option>
                            <option value="" <?php echo $doc_selected; ?>>Yearly</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                    <p class="instruct" id="instruct16"><small>How often does this test occur?</small></p>
                </li>
```

When someone selects the "daily" option, I want the div with the id of "daily" to show. If they select a different one, it needs to close the visible one and show the new selection.

I have done this before with click buttons and a single toggle, but I am unsure how to write this for such a large toggle, especially using a select "option". I assume my options will need ID's as well.

Comment: Please don't show us your PHP; it's entirely irrelevant. What's the rendered output, what HTML do you get from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 5 option elements, if you have 5 target elements that should be hidden/shown according to the selected option,  you can add a class to your target elements and use `eq` and `index` methods:

```
var $targets = $('.theTargets');

$('#Field16').change(function(){
    var i = $('option:selected', this).index();
    $targets.hide().eq(i).show();
});
```

In case that you want to select the target element by ID:

```
$(function(){
    var $targets = $('.theTargets'); // If they have a common class name

    $('#Field16').change(function(){
        var id = this.value.toLowerCase();
        $targets.hide().filter('#' + id).show();
    })
})
```

Comment: @greycode Have you put the code within document ready handler?

Comment: Nope, sorry! my mistake! I never know when to use document ready! Your's is corect!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change function for the select field, and grab the ID of the selected option.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //This will fire when an option is selected from <select>
        $("#Field16").change(function() {
            //Add a class to all div's so you can hide previous ones
            $(".whateveryourclassis").hide();

            //Get the ID of the selected option
            var selectedID = $(this).attr("id") + "div";

            //Show the right div. (assuming the div you want has the same ID as option
            //with "div" after it
            $("#" + selectedID).show();
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail? I dont understand how to implement this fully.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    $('li').hide()
    $('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

Comment: it will not hide all previous open `DIV`

Comment: okay but i think it will also not work because user don't want to hide all the `li`

Answer (score 0):

Building from tymeJV's answer,

I would give each of the divs which will be hidden/shown a class name such as `showhide`, then

```
$("#Field16").change(function() {
    //Get the ID of the desired div
    var selectedID = $(this).val();

    $(".showhide").hide();
    $("#" + selectedID).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

You can bind the select to an onchange event and grab the value like.

```
$('#Field16').bind('change',function(){
    $('.box').hide(); // All the elements you want to hide on change.
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XKLx8/

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you want:

**HTML**

```
<select id="Field16" style="margin-left: 0px;" name="" class="field select">
                            <option value="">None</option>
                            <option value="">Daily</option>
                            <option value="">Weekly</option>
                            <option value="">Monthly</option>
                            <option value="">Yearly</option>
                        </select>
<div id="none">I am None</div>
<div id="daily">I am Daily</div>
<div id="monthly">I am Monthly</div>
<div id="weekly">I am Weekly</div>
<div id="yearly">I am Yearly</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    hide_all();
    function hide_all(){
    $("#Field16 option").each(function(){
        var ids=$(this).text().toLowerCase();
        $('#'+ids).hide();
    });
    }
    $("#Field16").change(function(){
        hide_all();
        var val=$('option:selected',this).text().toLowerCase();
        $('#'+val).show();
    });

});
```

here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8wKzQ/